# python if-else loop can not excute correctly

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, operating-system

I want to get how many times core-dump file will be created, this file will be created and deleted, core-dump file is always named `core` in the path `/xty/tmp`. My code is below:

```
def get_core():

    core_path = '/xty/tmp'
    os.chdir(core_path)
    b='true'
    b_core='true'
    while True:
        if b=='true':#first time to get the time core file created
            if os.path.exists('/xty/tmp/core'):
                core_time = os.path.getctime('/xty/tmp/core')
                coredumps.append(core_time)
                tmp_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(float    (core_time)))
                times.append(tmp_time)
                b='false'
            else:
                pass   
        else:
            if os.path.exists('/xty/tmp/core'):
                core_time1 = os.path.getctime('/xty/tmp/core')
                for i in range(0,len(coredumps)):
                    if coredumps[i]==core_time1:
                        print  '111'
                        b_core='false'
                    else:
                        continue
                if b_core=='true':
                    coredumps.append(core_time1)
                    tmp_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime    (float(core_time1)))
                    times.append(tmp_time)

            else:
                pass
```

And this is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBh1B.png)
I use b_core to know if this file is a already existing file，but after I first time to get the creating time，I deleted the core file and created a new one, I can not get the second file creating time, the output console find only print `111`, can u help me ?
thank you

Comment: include your output in the post

Comment: @aydow hello,i already upload my output ,thank you

Comment: i already solve the problem because that i set b_core=='false',and when the first loop over，i do not set it be 'true' again